# Delete all values under a Registry key without deleting the sub-key

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Is there any function like `RegDeleteTree` to delete all the Values under a specific Registry Sub-key? I don't want to delete the Key, just its values.

If not, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way would be to enumerate the values with `RegEnumValue()` and delete them individually using `RegDeleteValue()`.

Or if the key doesn't have any sub-keys, just delete the whole key recursively and then recreate the parent key.

EDIT: This is a basic routine to illustrate how to enumerate and delete the values in a key (it only has minimal error checking).

```
DWORD dwNumValues, dwValueNameLen;
if (RegQueryInfoKey(hKey, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    &dwNumValues, &dwValueNameLen, 0, 0, 0) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    TCHAR* tchValName = new TCHAR[dwValueNameLen + 1];
    for (int i = dwNumValues - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        DWORD dwLen = dwValueNameLen + 1;
        if (RegEnumValue(hKey, i, tchValName, &dwLen, 0, 0, 0, 0) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            RegDeleteValue(hKey, tchValName);
    }
    delete[] tchValName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jonathan. Do I suppose I have to do a For or a While to join those two functions. Am I right?

Comment: I've added some example code of how to enum and delete the values.