# Show value name and data using RegEnumValue

Tags: c++, winapi

I have the following code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, wchar_t*argv[])
{

    std::locale::global(std::locale("spanish"));


    /*Declaración de variables*/

    HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    LPCTSTR lpSubKey = TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\RunMRU");
    DWORD ulOptions = 0;
    REGSAM samDesired = KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE;
    HKEY phkResult;
    DWORD dwIndex = 0;
    TCHAR lpValueName[16383];
    DWORD lpcchValueName = 16383;
    LPTSTR lpData="";

    long OpenK = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, lpSubKey, ulOptions, samDesired, &phkResult);

    if (OpenK == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        long R = RegEnumValue(phkResult, dwIndex, lpValueName, &lpcchValueName, NULL, NULL,(LPBYTE)lpData, NULL);


        if (R == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            cout << "The value and data is: \n" << lpValueName << ": " << lpData << endl;
            //printf(TEXT("(%d) %s\n"), lpValueName);
        }
        else
            cout << "Error: " << R << endl;

    }
    else if (OpenK == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        cout << "La sub-clave RunMRU no existe." << endl;
    }
    else if (OpenK == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
    {
        cout << "Acceso denegado al abrir la sub-clave RunMRU." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error al abrir la clave de registro. Código: " << OpenK << endl;

    }


    system("Pause");


}
```

I am trying to show both, the Value name, and its Data using the `RegEnumValue` in the first if (The value and data is:) but I can only show the Value name.

Is there any way to do that? I'm trying to figure out how to use the `lpData`, but I can't because I only receive error 87 (Incorrect parameters) or nothing (If I set NULL instead).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not providing a suitable buffer for `RegEnumValue()` to store the data.

```
LPTSTR lpData="";
```

This is just a string literal, of at most 2 bytes in size, and is almost certainly not writable anyway. You need to allocate an area of memory and pass that to `RegEnumValue()` to read the data back for each value.

Your first step should be to use `RegQueryInfoKey()` to find out how big the largest data value is. I showed you how to use this function in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255066/delete-all-values-under-a-registry-key-without-deleting-the-sub-key/19255134#19255134) to query the size of the largest value name - the process is the same. See the docs for [`RegQueryInfoKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find out which parameter provides the data size.

Once you know how big your largest item of data is, allocate a buffer for it:

```
void* pData = malloc(dwLargestValueSize);
// remember this buffer needs to be freed at the end with free()
```

You then pass that buffer, plus a value indicating its size, to `RegEnumValue()`.

Something else you need to be aware of is that registry values can be different types - `REG_DWORD`, `REG_SZ`, etc, and the data you get back from `RegEnumValue()` is the raw data. `RegEnumValue()` can also return a value indicating the type of data and if you're to properly interpret it, you absolutely need to check this as well.

Comment: Jonathan, would I have to work with the lpcMaxValueLen variable? If so, the buffer would have that value? (pData=malloc(lpcMaxValueLen) and the that value would be the lpData for RegEnumValue?

Answer (score 0):

Changes to your code to get a string value into lpData:

```
#define MAX_DATA_LENGTH 16383
char* lpData = new char[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
DWORD lpDataLength = MAX_DATA_LENGTH;

RegEnumValue(phkResult, dwIndex, lpValueName, &lpcchValueName, NULL, NULL, (unsigned char*)lpData, &lpDataLength);
```